InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException::Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket
I am creating a Cloudtrail trail and an S3 bucket to store all my logs. My trail has to be an org level trail and a multi region trail. I am setting up the S3 bucket policy from these AWS docs. My kms key policy allows cloudtrail to kms:GenerateDataKey*", "kms:DescribeKey", "kms:Decrypt.
 resource "aws_kms_key" "cloudtrail_kms_key" {
   description         = "KMS key for Cloudtrail S3 Bucket"
   enable_key_rotation = true
   multi_region        = true
 }

resource "aws_kms_key_policy" "cloudtrail_kms_key_policy" {
  key_id = aws_kms_key.cloudtrail_kms_key.key_id
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Id      = "cloudtrail-kms-key-policy",
    Statement : [
      {
        Sid       = "Enable IAM User Permissions"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = { AWS = "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:root" }
        Action    = "kms:*"
        Resource  = "*"
      },
      {
        Sid    = "Permitted KMS Key Services"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"]
        }
        Action   = ["kms:GenerateDataKey*", "kms:DescribeKey", "kms:Decrypt"]
        Resource = "*",
        "Condition" : {
          "StringEquals" : {
        "aws:SourceArn" : "arn:aws:cloudtrail:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:trail/${var.trail_name}"
      },
      "StringLike": {
         "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:cloudtrail:arn": "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:${var.aws_account_id}:trail/*"
      }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_cloudtrail" "trail" {
  depends_on                 = [aws_s3_bucket_policy.cloudtrail_bucket_policy]
  name                       = var.trail_name
  s3_bucket_name             = aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.id
  is_organization_trail      = true
  is_multi_region_trail      = true
  kms_key_id                 = aws_kms_key.cloudtrail_kms_key.arn
  enable_log_file_validation = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "cloudtrail_bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "cloudtrail_bucket_ownership_controls" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerEnforced"
  }
}

#Link to IAM policy : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/create-s3-bucket-policy-for-cloudtrail.html#org-trail-bucket-policy
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cloudtrail_bucket_policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck"
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions   = ["s3:GetBucketAcl"]
    resources = [aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.arn]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = ["arn:aws:cloudtrail:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:trail/${var.trail_name}"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "AWSCloudTrailWrite"
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions   = ["s3:PutObject"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.arn}/AWSLogs/${var.aws_account_id}/*"]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:x-amz-acl"
      values   = ["bucket-owner-full-control"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = ["arn:aws:cloudtrail:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:trail/${var.trail_name}"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "AllowOrganizationTrailToPutObjects"
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions   = ["s3:PutObject"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.arn}/AWSLogs/${var.organization_id}/*"]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:x-amz-acl"
      values   = ["bucket-owner-full-control"]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = ["arn:aws:cloudtrail:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:trail/${var.trail_name}"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "cloudtrail_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cloudtrail_bucket_policy.json
}

Yet I keep running into the following error :
Error: creating CloudTrail Trail (org-logs): operation error CloudTrail: CreateTrail, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 42aed73c-100f-43cb-b094-cd5d615bde1e, InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: 
Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket: cloudtrail-production-us-west-2-042518407502-ls (Service: AWSCloudTrail; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException; Request ID: 422be9b4-75da-4a97-8012-a80b99a9942a; Proxy: null)

Just as an additional point: I am indeed deploying this to the delegated administrator account so I know that is not an issue.
What am I doing wrong?

Is the aws_account_id equal to the ID of the organization management account?

@MarkoE. Yes it is. I am deploying this to the delegated account.

And is the bucket in us-east-1 maybe?

nope. i am deploying this in us-west-2

Let me start by saying I was able to reproduce exactly your same error:
InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException: Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket
only difference in my test I set is_organization_trail to false...

the policy
I started breaking down your policy, also looking at others doing similar things, one good example:
https://github.com/cloud-custodian/cloud-custodian/blob/main/tests/terraform/cloudtrail_success_log_metric_filter/main.tf
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.success-1.bucket}/*",

So I changed your first statement (AWSCloudTrailWrite) to match that:
resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.arn}/*"]
After that no more errors and a structure was created in the bucket:


the change
the difference in the line we changed:
["${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.arn}/*"]
VS
["${aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.arn}/prefix/AWSLogs/${var.aws_account_id}/*"]
... maybe that prefix is not supposed to be there

s3_key_prefix
Your resource "aws_cloudtrail" does not have a prefix defined, that is done with s3_key_prefix we can add that, and my code now looks like:
resource "aws_cloudtrail" "trail" {
  depends_on                 = [aws_s3_bucket_policy.cloudtrail_bucket_policy]
  name                       = var.trail_name
  s3_bucket_name             = aws_s3_bucket.cloudtrail_bucket.id
  is_organization_trail      = false
  is_multi_region_trail      = true
  kms_key_id                 = aws_kms_key.cloudtrail_kms_key.arn
  enable_log_file_validation = true
  s3_key_prefix              = "prefix"
}

bring the resource back to the original and it all applies correctly
and the bucket now has that "prefix" in the structure


full code from my tests
all my code while I was troubleshooting is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/commits/master/TerraForm/InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException/main.tf

Thank you so much for the hard work on this. however i am able to easily spin up the infra when setting the is_organization_trail to false. The prefix isn't the issue since that's just optional. My challenge is to get this running while setting is_organization_trail to true. I can understand that can be hard to mimic in a personal environment.

@Somethingwhatever Did you try with s3_key_prefix = "prefix" in your resource?  ... yes that is optional but you are enforcing it in your policy and it does not exist in your resource

ahh yeah i did. actually let me fix the policy as well. since i ended up not using the optional prefix and still ran into the same error. thank you.

Follow the same troubleshooting I did ... break down that policy use simpler resources you have to break this down further, the is_organization_trail makes it hard to test outside your env
